# Round number to n decimal places in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rounding

how to round 47.3476 to 47.35 in kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val num = 47.3476
val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")//set decimal format here
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
println(df.format(num)) //47.35
```

Comment: While code only answers might answer the question, it's better to offer an explanation of why the solution you are offering solves the problem, along with your code answer.